# <p:autoComplete> losing values during input

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm using `p:autoComplete` of Primefaces with following setup:

```
<p:autoComplete
      id="Nr"
      dropdown="true"
      autoHighlight="false"
      scrollHeight="300"
      value="#{View.Nr}"
      completeMethod="#{view.completeNr}">
           <p:ajax
               event="change"
               update="nrStatus" />
            <p:ajax
               event="itemSelect"
               listener="#{view.onNrSelect}"
               update="nrStatus" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

when user input needs longer than 300ms, `p:autoComplete` fires ajax-change-event. If user adds input during the fired change-event, the inputfield doesnt get the new input. I assume that, during change-event, the inputfield of `p:autoComplete` loses its focus.

**what I want:** 
first: no more lost inputs
second: fire new change event, if value of input changed since first change event.

**temporary solution:** increased "queryDelay"-attribute to 1000ms

**my question:** is there any possibility to realize this?

Comment: What is your PF version?

Comment: <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: Tried a 6.1-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: i'm still figuring out, how to get 6.1-SNAPSHOT :D

Comment: from github and build it yourself...